# Binding ComboBox to 2 DataSource: Table & Enum

Tags: c#, combobox, datasource

I have the next Enum:

```
public enum DoneStatus
{
    empty=0,
    succeed,
    failed
};
```

and the table *StatusTbl* with the column *MyStatus* which contain 0 / 1 / 2.

How can I display this information in a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn?

I tried to write the next:

```
ComboColumn.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DoneStatus));
ComboColumn.DataPropertyName = "DoneStatus";
ComboColumn.Name = "DoneStatus";
```

but I can see only all the options in the combo, I can't see the right selected value according to the value in the table.

I also tried to connect the combo a binding souce:

```
ComboColumn.DataSource = statusTblBindingSource;
ComboColumn.DataPropertyName = "MyStatus";
```

But then I only saw the int values (0/1/2) and not the string values.

Which DataSource should I use?

How can I combine between the DB and the enum in the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ComboColumn.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DoneStatus))
    .Cast<DoneStatus>()
    .Select(p => new { Key = (int)p, Value = p.ToString() })
    .ToList();
// you can change the display member and value member
// based on which value you have stored in database
ComboColumn.DisplayMember = "Key";
ComboColumn.ValueMember = "Value";
ComboColumn.DataPropertyName = "MyStatus";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write :

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(DoneStatus));
```

Comment: Still, the ComboBox is not connected to the DB table and doesn't display the proper value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps here

1) bind the enum to the combo box data source, so it can have the list of items to select.

```
ComboColumn.DataSource = Enum.GetName(typeof(DoneStatus));
```

2) set the selected item from what you read from the DB query.

```
ComboColumn.DataPropertyName = statusTblBindingSource["MyStatus"]; // See Note.
```

Note: I cannot remember the exact syntax of getting a values from the table for a given column, but I think it was similar to the line I wrote.